# What is the difference between micro-kernel and monolithic-kernel?

Tags: kernel

I heard that Unix/Linux is a monolithic-kernel whereas Hurd is micro-kernel. So, I want to know what is the difference between these kernel type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537850/what-is-difference-between-monolithic-and-micro-kernel

Answer (score 0):

**Monolithic kernel** is a single large processes running entirely in a single address space (kernel space) where as **Microkernels**, the kernel is broken down into separate processes. Some process run in **kernel space** and some run in **user space**.

Reference:

http://www.8bitavenue.com/2012/11/microkernel-vs-monolithic-os-architectures/